# Почему бы не добавить полученные за вопрос знаки возле вопроса?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, модерация, знаки

Например, пользователь получил знак "Хороший вопрос". И можно чтобы не заходить на профиль пользователя и искать этот знак, их можно высветить рядом с вопросом. Например, так: 

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Неплохая идея, но лучше это сделать не полноценным изображением знака с его названием, а как-то менее заметно. Например, маленьким изображением медали под рейтингом, при наведении на которую будет выводиться что-то вроде "За данный вопрос были присуждены знаки: ... ". Ну и помимо вопросов, для ответов тоже можно это сделать.

Answer (score 10):

Имхо, это и так видно по голосам. И знаки всё же для пользователя, а не для сообщений. Читающему сообщение, как мне кажется, совсем нет необходимости знать, сколько всякого добра получил участник за читаемое в данный момент сообщение. Хотя сама идея и выглядит интересно, её реализация видится мне избыточной перегрузкой интерфейса.

Comment: А если кто-то не знает, или забыл? Или знак не за голоса или просмотры?

Comment: @VerNick подобные вещи отвлекают от основного. На SO первичны вопросы и ответы, а всё эти финтифлюшки вторичны. Поэтому не стоит их отображать везде, чтоб глаза не мозолили.